# Changing desktop icon size in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, 19.04, desktop-icons

I just went from 18.10 to 19.04 and the desktop icons and shortcuts are there but they are too large.
Previously I could decrease their size from nautilus but now they seem to not respond to that and as far as I know, the desktop icons are no longer under nautilus.

I was wondering if there is a way to decrease the size of the icons already on my desktop instead of installing some new extension to create new icons and then resize them.

Comment: Is your resolution set to 1366x768 ? My laptop has the same resolution and Even after 2 months of updating I am still facing same issue. Text , Icons, Title bars are too big for my preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, desktop ions are not anymore provided by nautilus. They are now provided by a Gnome Shell Extension. The icons can be resized, but the options are limited to some preset sizes and are currently not exposed in the default user interface.

**Using Tweaks** - The easiest way to change the icon size is to install Gnome Tweaks (aka "Tweaks"). On the "Extensions" tab of Tweaks, you will see a cog next to the "Desktop icons" extension. Click the cog to access configuration options for the extension, which include a choice between "Small", "Standard" and "Large" desktop icons.

**Using the terminal** - Alternatively, you can control the size with a terminal command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons icon-size 'standard'
```

Other possibilities instead of `'standard'` are `'small'` and `'large'` You can learn this with the command

```
gsettings range org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons icon-size
```

To reset to default:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons icon-size
```

**Customize icon size** - *For advanced users only*

Only three preset icon sizes are available in the extension's preferences. Customizing these sizes unfortunately requires hacking the source code of the extension because icon size presets are hard-coded in the file `prefs.js`.

```
const ICON_SIZE = { 'small': 48, 'standard': 64, 'large': 96 };
const ICON_WIDTH = { 'small': 120, 'standard': 128, 'large': 128 };
const ICON_HEIGHT = { 'small': 98, 'standard': 114, 'large': 146 };
```

The system wide extension is installed in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano`.

Comment: Ok apparently it was already at small but their small is way too big for my taste. Can't I change it in a continuous manner? As in using numbers instead of discrete values?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but apparently there is no option other than pre determined small, standard, large right? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Indeed, the options are limited. Thank you for pointing it out. It is important soI I updated the first paragraph of my answer to make that clear from the start. A way around this would probably require hacking into the extension's code.

Comment: Hacking, that is indeed how it can be done. I will add for completeness.

Comment: Thanks man, all good now. God do I love this OS